# Connect external USB GPS to Windows Maps

Tags: windows-10, gps

Trying to connect external USB GPS device to laptop that runs Windows with standard Maps software. Windows detects GPS device as virtual com port COM6. But how to tell Maps to use this GPS device. Where to find souch settings?

Comment: It would help if you said the software you were using also. To see if we can integrate it.

Comment: What "usb gps" do you have?

Comment: Also you may look into [GPSDirect](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9_LW1s_zMAhXECBoKHRM1AV8QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.turboirc.com%2Fgps7%2F&usg=AFQjCNGvQtYxqfiE8TZD51rD8VvLcD8IsQ) as this could help with your situation and act as a driver for your com port. Look into it.

Comment: I'm using g-star IV bu-353s4 device and Maps - standar software that comes with Windows 10